# What is recommended to have Multiple Product-Set for Multiple Product-Category in Google Cloud-Vision-Product Search?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision, google-product-search

I am looking for recommendation for creation of a product-set in Google Cloud Vision Product Search, what will be the best practice to create a product-set for multiple product category?

Let say, I have a retailers products. The products are around 100 thousand and have more than 100 category (like shoes, men-shirt, women-shirt) in it. so what is the best way to create a product-set in  Google Cloud Vision Product Search.
To have all products in one single product-set or it should have different product-set in a different product?
If it has a single product-set does it affects the vision-search?
If its different product-set for different category, How I will search the image in different product-set and How it will work with search-image containing multiple product in an image?

I am following this link : 
https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/
But there is no such recommendation is given in it.

Search-Image having multiple product in it should give search results for all products.

Answer (score 1):

Product Search has a few [categories](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/product-categories) to choose from and the categories are quite broad. It sounds like all of your items are different kinds of apparel, so you could create all of your products with the "apparel-v2" category.

You can put all of your apparel Products into a single Product Set so that you search across your whole catalog of Products.